# Event viewer displays warning message on BlackBerry server

Tags: blackberry

WARNING BlackBerry Policy Service(warning, 20000, warning)[SCS::PerformITAdminQueueHealthCheck - HealthCheck found issues, ]{4}, eventlog: 4 > warning

Doe anybody know what the above error message means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this particular error, but I've looked at a number of "Warning" level messages from our BES.

In most cases the answer from RIM is that the messages are partly informational and should be expected during normal operation. Sometimes they're a hint to deeper problems, but unless users are reporting problems I just ignore all BES messages with severity of Warning or below.

Comment: I hate to say it, but we've gotten the same response from Blackberry support. If users aren't reporting any problems, then we simply ignore any errors or warnings in the event logs related to BES.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It is a confirmation of what I also got from RIM. I think I will indeed ignore these warnings, because there are no known problems. Thanks!